# Automatic configuration reinitialization in Spring

Tags: spring

In Log4j, there is a feature wherein the system can be initialized to do a configure and watch with an interval. This allows for the log4j system to reload its properties whenever the property file is changed. Does the spring framework have such a Configuration Observer facility wherein the Configuration is reloaded when it changed. The Configuration that needs reloading is not the Springs's applicationContext.xml but  various other configuration files that are initialized using the Spring initialization beans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a utility that does something similar to Log4J [here](http://www.wuenschenswert.net/wunschdenken/archives/138). It's basically an extension to PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer that reloads properties when they change.

Comment: This was adapted at https://github.com/Unicon/springframework-addons/wiki/Auto-reloading-properties-files

Comment: @Vadzim link is dead!   This might help us in above case http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html

Comment: @pramodc84, updated links: http://maven-repository.com/artifact/net.unicon.springframework/springframework-addons/0.1, https://github.com/UniconLabs/springframework-addons/blob/master/src/main/java/net/unicon/springframework/addons/properties/ReloadingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java, https://github.com/knightliao/disconf/blob/master/disconf-client/src/main/java/com/baidu/disconf/client/addons/properties/ReloadingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Spring does not provide such a utility. However there is a 3rd party tool, [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) that enables you to update an entire web application (including the Spring configuration) without requiring a server restart.

A free trial is available, and the purchase price is fairly inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

I would be extra cautious with reloading spring application context.

What do you expect to happen with singleton beans? If an object has a reference to singleton bean, should it be updated?

Comment: I don not want to reload spring applicationcontext.xml or any of the spring beans already loaded. I will try out the solution Phill Sacre posted.

Answer (score 0):

I develop using JRebel and I would be very wary of expecting it to refresh your configuration. Works fine with Java, not with Spring though.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to add context, I have done that  in the following way :

```
public class ApplicationContextUtil
{
   static String[] configFiles = {"applicationContextParent.xml"};

   private static ApplicationContext context = null;

   static
   {
       context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ( configFiles );
   }

   public static void addContext( String[] newConfigFiles )
   {
       // add the new context to the previous context
       ApplicationContext newContext =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ( newConfigFiles, context );
       context = newContext;
   }   
   public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext ()
   {
       // return the context
       return context;
   }
}
```

This is your context provider class. For details, you can look at [my blog](https://sites.google.com/site/sohelasrafblog/spring/spring-configuration)