# Configure hibernate to use "show-sql=false" temporarily

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a java progam using Maven, JPA, Eclipse, Jenkins. While developing I have the setting

spring:
 jpa:
 show-sql: true

in my application.yml file which works fine. Now, for a load test I have huge chunk of data. If I execute the test it works fine in Eclipse, but fails in Maven as the SureFire Plugin fails on such large console output. I can make it work by redirecting the console to a file, but that won't work for Jenkins and it won't work if I start the tests altogether because I want to see the result on the console obviously. So I would like to have this setting (show-sql) be switched off temporarily. I suppose it must live somewhere in the JPA / Hibernate configuration classes, but I couldn't find any combination yet that would allow me to change it.

Any advise is appreciated,
 Stephan

The closest I suppose I came to it was by this:

```
entityManager.setProperty( "hibernate.show_sql", false );
entityManager.setProperty( "spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql", false );
entityManager.setProperty( "javax.persistence.hibernate.show_sql", false );
```

Where the entityManager is autowired to the component. But when reading those properties, the return is some values from a completely different namespace (some timeout values), so I reckon I am in the wrong corner...

Comment: Use spring to load test properties, which are separated from development/production

Comment: That's actually in place, so in production is no problem at all. But in test I have quite a large test with many similar requests to check for the complete queue and receive a guess for the performance.
So in general I need the output, but for that test I don't. Or at least not after the first few queries because then I see the system in the log.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are also using spring, what you can do is using profiles which is available since version 3. See this link for more information: [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). You can active profiles during runtime. For example in application-loadtest.yml would then be your configuration for your loadtests.

Or as alternative you can add this properties as parameter environment variables or as command line argument: [Externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

I hope this helps.

regards, WiPu

Comment: So as a conclusion I understand it is just really not possible to change these settings during runtime / between start and stop of the Spring boot container?
Well, if its not possible I see that I should consider alternatives and then I would probably prefer using the profiles as you mentioned which I have used shallowly before.

Comment: What could work, but i haven't tried this myself, is to rebuild the entity manager  at some point with the new properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998502/java-spring-recreate-specific-bean. So you can run some tests and then rebuild the entity manager with enabled/disabled sql log.

Comment: Well, yeah about that was exactly my idea as outlined in the initial post more or less. But then I don't have the correct properties path. I have been reading out the entityManager to check what's in there - collecting information is not a bad thing more often than not. But then I found completely different values, the once I set in the application.yml (and want to change by code) are not there so I suppose its not the right corner to manipulate them, is it?

Comment: At least I don't have an idea what properties paths to use... Found no proper documentation to use. If found this: "https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties" but it didn't really got me there...

Comment: i quickly checked it in a project where i can enable / disable the show_sql. What i found is that in this project (spring boot 2.X/ hibernate 5.X) the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` has the jpaPropertyMap hibernate.show_sql=true. This bean builds a `EntityManagerFactory` (implementation from hibernate: `SessionFactoryImpl`) with those properties.

Comment: As alternative you can look into something like this: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-log-jdbc-statements/. There the enabled / disable could be easier to achive. Or just disable the hibernate logger respectivly change the loglevel during runtime which might be the simplest solution.