# How to auto configure programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot kafka application. My brokers are recycled every few days.  The old brokers  are deprovisioned and new brokers are provisioned.

I have a scheduler which is checking for brokers every few hours. I would like to make sure as soon as the we have new brokers, 
we should reload all the Spring Kafka related beans. Very similar to KafkaAutoConfiguration except I want a trigger on broker value change and load the auto configuration programmatically.

How do I call the auto configure programmatically whenever the old brokers are replaced with new one ?

Comment: See if any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218086/how-to-reinitialize-a-spring-bean , https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Reload-External-Configuration-on-Runtime-in-Spring-Boot/, http://www.tothenew.com/blog/loading-and-removing-bean-at-run-time-in-spring-application/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998502/java-spring-recreate-specific-bean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your requirements sounds like *Config Server* in Spring Cloud:https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR2/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_2.html#_spring_cloud_config_2 with its `@RefreshScope` feature: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR2/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#refresh-scope.

So, you need to specify your own beans and mark them with that annotation:

```
@Bean
@RefreshScope
public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> kafkaConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(this.properties.buildConsumerProperties());
}

@Bean
@RefreshScope
public ProducerFactory<?, ?> kafkaProducerFactory() {
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
            this.properties.buildProducerProperties());
    String transactionIdPrefix = this.properties.getProducer().getTransactionIdPrefix();
    if (transactionIdPrefix != null) {
        factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix);
    }
    return factory;
}
```

These two beans rely on the configuration properties for connection to Apache Kafka broker and that is really fully enough to have them refreshable. Whenever a `ContextRefreshedEvent` happens these beans are going to be re-initialized with a fresh configuration properties.

I think the `ConsumerFactory` consumers (`MessageListenerContainer` and `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`) have to be restarted on that event as well. The point is that `MessageListenerContainer` starts a long-living process and therefore caches a `KafkaConsumer` instance for the `poll` purposes.

All the `ProducerFactory` consumers don't need to be restarted. Even if `KafkaProducer`  is cached in the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` it is going to be reinitialized during `@RefreshScope` phase.

**UPDATE**

> I don’t use config server. I get the new hosts from consul catalog service.

Right, I didn't say that you use a Config Server. That just looks for me similar way. So, from big height I would really take a look into a Config Client implementation for your Consul catalog solution.

Nevertheless you still can emit a `RefreshEvent` which will trigger all your `@RefreshScope`'d beans to be reloaded. For that purpose you need to implement an `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` and emit that event whenever you have update from Consul. Remember: Kafka listener containers must be restarted. For that purpose you can listen for the `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent` since you really are interested in the restart only when all the `@RefreshScope` have been refreshed.

More about *refresh scope*: https://gist.github.com/dsyer/a43fe5f74427b371519af68c5c4904c7

Comment: Thank you Artem. I don’t use config server. I get the new hosts from consul catalog service. Is it possible to invoke the context refresh event programmatically from the scheduler ? I’m using RefreshScope already in my project. How do we differentiate this RefreshScope from others ?

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again - So I finally got around to working on this - Regarding this _Nevertheless you still can emit a RefreshEvent which will trigger all your @RefreshScope'd beans to be reloaded._  how does the refreshscope knows what do update for the factory ? All got changed was brokers list - meaning how does `new RefreshEvent(this, brokers, "new brokers")` translates to new factory ? I'm missing that link.

Comment: I think you need to start a new SO thread. It is kinda lost already in this old one - more than year ago...