# Change SessionFactory datasource jdbcurl late in runtime

Tags: spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm writing a desktop java application for an environment without a network connection. I'm trying to store the application data as securely as I can in an encrypted in-process hsqldb, with an unencrypted user information hsqldb. Hsqldb requires that the crypto_key be set in the jdbcurl when the connection is created. My application uses hibernate to do persistence and Spring to do configuration and injection.

My current scheme is to store username, password hash, salt and the encrypted database's crypto_key in the unencrypted user table. The crypto_key is protected by an asymmetric encryption using the user's password as the key. Thus, the application doesn't know what the crypto_key for the application data is until after it has been running long enough to load a gui, and authenticate the user.

Here is my current applicationContext.xml. Spring uses it to get Hibernate going and functioning.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.domain" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.service" />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="userDataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" 
        value="jdbc:hsqldb:./ReviewDatabase/users" />
    <property name="username" value="reviewer" />
    <property name="password" value="$kelatonKey" />
</bean>


<bean id="mainDataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" 
        value="jdbc:hsqldb:./ReviewDatabase/data" /> <!-- TODO: ;crypt_key=;crypt_type=AES -->
    <property name="username" value="reviewer" />
    <property name="password" value="$kelatonKey" />
</bean>

<bean id="userSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="userDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.company.domain.AppUser</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mainSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
<!--                <value>com.companu.domain.Person</value> -->
<!--                <value>com.company.domain.Thing</value> -->
<!--                <value>com.company.domain.Thing1</value> -->
<!--                <value>com.company.domain.Thing2</value> -->
<!--                <value>com.company.domain.Review</value> -->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <pro key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="mainTransactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mainSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="userTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="userSessionFactory" /> 
</bean>
</beans>
```

Here's an example of a class where I would like to have the SessionFactory injected

```
@Repository("ReviewDao")
public class HibernateReviewDao implements ReviewDao{

private SessionFactory mainSessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setMainSessionFactory(
        SessionFactory mainSessionFactory){
    this.mainSessionFactory = mainSessionFactory;
}

@Override
@Transactional(value = "mainTransactionManager")
public void store(Review review) {
    mainSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(review);

}

@Override
@Transactional(value = "mainTransactionManager")
public void delete(Long reviewId) {
    Review review = (Review)mainSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .get(Review.class, reviewId);
    mainSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(review);
}
}
```

And finally, here's what I've tried to do after authenticating the user and getting that crypto_key.

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:hsqldb:./ReviewDatabase/data2;crypt_key=" + secret + ";crypt_type=AES";
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .applySetting("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect")
    .applySetting("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
    .applySetting("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update")
    .applySetting("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
    .applySetting("hibernate.connection.url", jdbcUrl)
    .applySetting("hibernate.connection.username", "reviewer")
    .applySetting("hibernate.connection.password", "$kelatonKey")
    .buildServiceRegistry();

    SessionFactory mainSessionFactory = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.company.domain.Review.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.company.domain.Person.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.company.domain.Thing.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.company.domain.Thing1.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.company.domain.Thing2.class)
        .buildMetadata()
        .buildSessionFactory();
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager htm = 
            (HibernateTransactionManager)context.getBean("mainTransactionManager");
    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(mainSessionFactory, "mainSessionFactory"); 
    htm.setSessionFactory(mainSessionFactory);
```

However, with that, the first query to the object above results in `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`

How can I change the jdbcurl long after hibernate has initialized, dependencies have been injected and other various kinds of tom-foolery has occurred? 
I've been putting this part of development off, hoping Google would eventually come through, but I'm out of ideas to search for. All answers will be accepted with sheepish humility :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this might help, [Can I replace a Spring bean definition at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041300/can-i-replace-a-spring-bean-definition-at-runtime) , you could dummy up the bean properties to start with and then change the bean in runtime.

Comment: 24 hours later I came up with something that works, but the answer behind that link can be applied much more generically(In a good way). Add that in with an idea of how to use LocalSessionFactoryBean, and I'd call this one solved.

Answer (score 0):

So, the missing bit of the recipe was LocalSessionFactoryBean. It got the sessionFactory setup  so I could just replace the sessionFactories that are created at initialization. 
Here's the code I had to change from the question

```
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager htm = 
            (HibernateTransactionManager)context.getBean("mainTransactionManager");
    Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[5];
    classes[0] =  com.company.domain.Thing1.class;
    classes[1] =  com.company.domain.Thing2.class;
    classes[2] =  com.company.domain.Person.class;
    classes[3] =  com.company.domain.Thing.class;
    classes[4] =  com.company.domain.Review.class;

    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:hsqldb:./ReviewDatabase/data3;crypt_key=" + secret + ";crypt_type=AES";

    java.util.Properties hibernateProperties = new java.util.Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", jdbcUrl);
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "reviewer");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "$kelatonKey");


    LocalSessionFactoryBean slfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    slfb.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    slfb.setAnnotatedClasses(classes);
    try {
        slfb.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.warn("Cannot connection to application database");
        Log.write(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        Log.write(e.getStackTrace());
        return;
    }
    SessionFactory mainSessionFactory = slfb.getObject();
    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(mainSessionFactory, "mainSessionFactory");

    htm.setSessionFactory(mainSessionFactory);  
    for(ListenForNewSessionFactory dao : daos){
        dao.setNewSessionFactory(mainSessionFactory);
    }
```

I had each Dao implement an interface to set the sessionFactory, and had each of them add themselves to a static list on initialization. It's not very reusable, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following hack - wherever I needed a `SessionFactory`, I used a `SessionFactoryFactory` (below) instead - delegates the only `SessionFactory` method I actually use.

```
@Component
public class SessionFactoryFactory {
    @Autowired
    private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean;

    @Autowired
    private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (null == sessionFactory) {
            sessionFactory = sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session openSession() {
        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    public void updateDataSourceUrl() throws IOException {
        sessionFactory = null;
        sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```