# updating the value read using value annotation in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a properties file say as follows:

```
apple=1
mango=2
banana=3
pineapple=4
```

I am using value annotation in the java program to access the values. I have a method in my class that computes a value i want to update the apple attribute in the properties file with the value that the method returns.

```
public class test {

    @Value("${apple}")
    private int apple;

    public void testMethod() {
        int new_val = 0;  
        if (apple > 0) 
            new_val = 300;
        else
            new_val = 200;
        // now i want to update the value of apple in the file to new_val,(apple = new_val) other attributes should remain unchanged. 
    }
}
```

can someone let me know how to update the value in the properties file. In this example i want my properties file to become

```
apple=300
mango=2
banana=3
pineapple=4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update field annotated with @Value in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478679/update-field-annotated-with-value-in-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

Usually we defines constant values in properties, so it does not change.
But if it is your requirement to change it.

You can do it like:
1) Using [Apache Commons Configuration library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/)

```
PropertiesConfiguration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration("yourproperty.properties");
props.setProperty("apple", "300");
conf.save();
```

2) Using Java input and output stream

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("yourproperty.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("yourproperty.properties");
props.setProperty("apple", "300");
props.store(out, null);
out.close();
```