# Change property value of a existing bean in spring at run time

Tags: spring

I have a web application deployed on Tomcat server. I have the following bean `hiveDataSource` created in my application-context.xml:

```
<!-- Hive Data Source for Connection Pooling -->
    <bean id="hiveDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/demo48" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" />
        <property name="username" value="hive" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
    </bean>
```

I want to change the value of property URL, username and password at run time for bean `hiveDataSource`. Is there any way to change these property values at runtime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041300/can-i-replace-a-spring-bean-definition-at-runtime might answer your question

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) says that these fields have `protected` access, so you wont be able to change their values. 
Even if you do, by using reflection or in some other way, it's not likely that data source would just pick up these new values. It would probably have to be restarted or reinitialized in some way.

Comment: One more Question: if I have a bean defined for some user defined class, and it has public properties, SO how can I change the property values for that particular bean at run time?

Comment: @Upadhyay You can get the bean from spring context, and change its field values, something like this `MyClass myClass = applicationContext.getBean("myClass")`