# Best way to override beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have an application that consists of 2 modules.

First of them is main one and it can work without second module installed.

I have beans with default implementation defined in `beans.xml` file of main module. And when installing second module I want to keep the ids of those beans but change the implementation to use new classes.

What is the best way to do that?

`beans.xml` of first module:

```
...
<bean id="myCoolService" class="com.blabla.defaultCoolServiceImpl">
...
```

and after the installation of second module I want to use the implementation of `myCoolService` that is defined in second module.

**Upd:**
Spring version is 3.2.4.
I need to make as little changes as possible so I need to continue using xml-driven configuration.

Comment: Is JavaConfig (using @Bean annotation for example) an option ? Which Spring version ?

Comment: do you want to use beans from second module into main? if so you can create new Newbeans.xml and set <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> to Newbeans.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I replace a Spring bean definition at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041300/can-i-replace-a-spring-bean-definition-at-runtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is introducing a common interface (I guess one should already be present):

```
public interface MyInterface {
    //...
}
```

And then in the main module annotate the default implementation with `@Service`

```
@Service
public class DefaultImplementation implements MyInterface {
    //...
}
```

Then, if one of your modules needs to override this implementation, use the `@Primary`-annotation:

```
@Service
@Primary
public class OverridingImplementation implements MyInterface {
    //...
}
```

Then, the following code:

```
@Inject
private MyInterface myInterface;
```

will inject `DefaultImplementation` if `OverridingImplementation` is not scanned, and inject `OverridingImplementation` (without complaining about multiple beans) if it is scanned.

Comment: thanks! that's what was looking for - elegant solution with minimum side-effect :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is going through a proxy, that redirects to the proper implementation. The proxy would normally redirect to the default. It will redirect to module 2 if it is available.

To help the proxy figure out what is available, you may need to have

1. a member that always points to the default implementation using "name" property.
2. have a method to register a different bean as the alternate implementation.

For example

Inside MyProxy:

```
@Autowired
public void setDefaultWorker(Worker defaultWorker) {
    this.defaultWorker = defaultWorker;
}

private Worker defaultWorker;

private Worker alternateWorker;

public void registerAlternateWorker(Worker alternateWorker) {
    this.alternateWorker = alternateWorker;
}

//To use the worker
private Worker getWorker() {
    return alternateWorker == null? defaultWorker : alternateWorker;
}
```

In Module 1, your default implementation bean should be declared as having the defaultWorker as name

```
<bean id="defaultWorker" class="MyDefaultWorkerImpl"/>
```

Module 2 can register itself to the proxy registry on startup using SmartLifeCycle.

Answer (score 0):

if possible,use :

```
<bean id="myCoolService" class="${IMPL_CLASS_NAME}"/>
```

Define impl class in a  property file.

```
IMPL_CLASS_NAME=com.blabla.SecondMduleCoolServiceImpl
```

OR other approach could be :

Lets say your defaultCoolServiceImpl and SecondMduleCoolServiceImpl implement ICoolService interface

You define these bean and an implementation of FactoryBean as below :

```
<bean id="mydefaultServiceimpl" class="com.blabla.defaultCoolServiceImpl">
<bean id="secondModuleCoolserviceimpl" class="com.blabla.SecondMduleCoolServiceImpl">
<bean id="myCoolService" class="com.blabla.ImplSelector"/>

public class ImplSelector implements FactoryBean<ICoolService>, ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext iApplicationContext;
    // @Value("#{corePropertyConfigurer['defaultOrCool']}") you can injcet via property file.
    private String defaultOrCool = "cool" ;
    @Override
    public ICoolService getObject() throws Exception {
        if (StringUtils.equals(defaultOrCool, "default")) {
            return iApplicationContext.getBean("mydefaultServiceimpl", ICoolService.class);
        }
        return iApplicationContext.getBean("secondModuleCoolserviceimpl", ICoolService.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ICoolService.class;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        iApplicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Then you can access myCoolService via autowiring or applicationContext.getBean("myCoolService", ICoolService.class);