# Switching between property files dynamically by changing environment name in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, environment-variables

I was wondering if there is any way that we can set the value of environment variable dynamically without restarting the server so that different property files might get accessed based on the value of currently set environment.

Consider these are my two property files:

```
config-dev.properties
config-prod.properties
```

Now since I have appended the name of environment with every file, so I want to know that is it possible that I dynamically change or set the value of environment name and the corresponding property file will be used without restarting the server.

I know how to set the **env.name** in configuration XML file.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config-${env.name}.properties>
```

I want to change the environment name programmatically so the correct property file can be used when it is accessed.

Comment: <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config-${env.name}.properties> is one way to do it. where your env.name is the run configuration can be the startup parameter you set. 

Another way to do it is to use the Spring bean Profile. where you define a profile and the beans defined for those profile would be loaded during the Spring container startup. 

Since your Spring container has already started, and the beans are already loaded. now you do want to load a different set of beans without restarting the Spring container. I am not sure about that.

Comment: @Hrishikesh my problem is this only that I need to do this without restarting the application or server.

Comment: So u use the same server for Prod as well as DEv?

Comment: yes actually I am trying to deploy this on cloud (Google App Engine) so usually I cannot setup multiple servers over there.

Comment: you could reload spring context, but I'm not sure this prod is also dev is a good idea (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534030/reloading-refreshing-spring-configuration-file-without-restarting-the-servlet-co)

Answer (score 0):

`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config-${env.name}.properties>` is one way to do it. where your env.name is the run configuration can be the startup parameter you set.

Another way to do it is to use the Spring bean Profile. where you define a profile and the beans defined for those profile would be loaded during the Spring container startup.

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean .... />
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:conf/properties/dev.properties" />
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
    <bean .... />
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:conf/properties/prod.properties" />
</beans>
```

I am not sure about changing it without restarting the server. since your Spring container has already started, and the beans are already loaded. now you do want to load a different set of beans without restarting the Spring container. I am not sure about that.

The basic reason for that according to me would be upon, how do you change the already autowired dependencies during runtime without affecting any other running application classes? What about a functionality which is being executed and you want to change the DB URL through the switch in the properties file? How do you control that?

Comment: I am not willing to restart the autowired dependencies and beans instead I want to change the only the property file to be used because that property file might have a param for paypal integration URL so paypal offers sandbox mode as well production mode so I need to switch among these modes dynamically either by switching the property file name or by changing the env variable name.

Comment: I am well aware of this **<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config-${env.name}.properties>** I just want to change the enviornment name programatically so the correct property file configs can be used.