# spring -how loading of bean to be decided at runtime

Tags: spring

this is asked in a technical interview

suppose there are three version of a class and they are configured as three beans, but which one is to be loaded/injected has to be decided at runtime.
Is this can be done using callBack method/Interfaces like BeanNameAware etc?

Comment: what do you mean by `loaded/injected`? Do you mean `instatiation` or `inject new bean definition`. If you mean dynamic bean definition change in runtime a suppose you can look at `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext` interface. Doc says that it can be used for that.

Comment: isn't it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534030/reloading-refreshing-spring-configuration-file-without-restarting-the-servlet-co the same?

Comment: Thanks for the link and showing the initial path , i will look into AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext

Comment: MyClass myClass = applicationContext.getBean("myClass");