# Reloading spring configuration in IntelliJ embedded tomcat deployment

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I want to flush the tomcat lib conf use during IntelliJ embedded deploy.

I tested:

1. reload artifact,
2. restart server,
3. drop .IntelliJIdea13\system\tomcat , .IntelliJIdea13\system\compile-server.

but my `tomcat7/lib/confEnv.xml` is never reloaded.
The file is a spring bean configuration in the tomcat7/lib directory, (I'm not architect on this project)

The last time i need to reboot my computer.

I've tried the "actions" dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) in IntelliJ for help, but to no avail.

Comment: Make it clear that we're talking about a Spring configuration file that's not getting picked up. Make other's understand what "ctrl+shift+A" does. Also, this isn't a tomcat problem and it *should* be fixed by restarting the servlet container. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534030/reloading-refreshing-spring-configuration-file-without-restarting-the-servlet-co for help.

Comment: thanks for clarification ctrl+shift+A was just a litle joke. My issue is not about spring, but about intellij that don't reload change conf when i restart tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij mix use of configuration file incoming from server lib directory, and from an other conf source folder, normaly the seconde conf folder is packaged only with a maven profil for run with jetty. It was because my profil "jetty" is select by default in intellij conf (project import configuration).