# Configuration file changes at runtime for a standalone app?

Tags: spring, runtime, implementation

Say I have a Swing/Spring standalone application. I am wondering whether Spring does detect runtime changes to its configuration file such as this one (assuming the file is on the classpath):

Commenting second bean and adding first bean as below:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="randonNumberGenerator"  class="com.me.MyGenerator"/>

    <!--
    <bean id="randonNumberGenerator"  class="com.someoneelse.ADifferentGenerator"/>
    -->
</beans>
```

Will Spring change the implementation at runtime as expected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic configuration reinitialization in Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461710/automatic-configuration-reinitialization-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Spring provides a way to reload the configuration on-the-fly. It could be possible by re-instantiating the entire ApplicationContext, but that would mean that all beans are recreated etc., and internal state of the software would probably fly out the window in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the "AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext" to refresh the context.

```
AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext refreshableContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext (  "applicationContextRefreshable.xml" );
 refreshableContext.refresh ( );
```

For details you can have a look [here](https://sites.google.com/site/sohelasrafblog/spring/spring-configuration)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot. Feel free to edit more useful information into this answer and flag to undelete.